# Installing LAMP - PHP not connecting with MySQL - Why?

Tags: php, mysql, apache2, lamp, ubuntu-14.04

Am followoing this amazingly simple LAMP tutorial
http://ubuntuserverguide.com/2014/06/how-to-install-lamp-in-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts.html

- Installing Apache
- Installing MySQL
- Installing PHP

The **PROBLEM** is:

- When I check on my brower localhost/phpmysql.php
- I just see BLANK PAGE
- If the php had been runned i should see either CONGRATULATIONS or
  ERROR message back.

> ```
>  <?php
>     $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","passwordxxxxxx");
>     if (!$con)
>     {
>      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
>     }
>     else
>     {
>      echo "Congrats! connection established successfully";
>     }
>     mysql_close($con);
>   ?>
> ```

Is there any error on this PHP code maybe? 
For example: if the password is wrong setup on the PHPMYSQL.PHP file I should get back and ERROR MESSAGE couse i have a ECHO.

Why am getting a blank response? any idea of some workaround?
Thanks

Comment: blank page = something blew up and you've got all debug output options turned off. enable `display_errors` and `error_reporting` in your php.ini, then try again.

Comment: I did so, but I still getting a blank page. Any other idea?

Comment: Do you have your php running? make a simple page as `<?php echo "Working"; ?>` and check the output

Comment: I got back. a blank screen with the word "Working"

Comment: Everything is in your web directory? for example like /home/www/

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: thanks for all your comments!

Answer (score 0):

After I installed phpMyAdmin, it is working suddenly the PHP file, and I get back all the time: Connected successfully